# When creating LangChain custom tool, how can I add new property

Tags: python, oop, langchain

I want to create a custom tool class with an additional property, let's say `number`. How can I change this code so that it doesn't throw an error?

Code:

```
from langchain.tools import BaseTool


class MyTool(BaseTool):
    name = "Whatever"
    description = "Whatever"
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = 123
    
    def _run(self):
        pass
    
    def _arun(self):
        pass


tool = MyTool()
```

Error:

```
ValueError: "MyTool" object has no field "number"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
from langchain.tools import BaseTool


class MyTool(BaseTool):
    name = "Whatever"
    description = "Whatever"
    number: int
        
    def __init__(self, number: int = 123):
        super(MyTool, self).__init__(number=number)
       
    def _run(self):
        print("run:", self.number)
    
    def _arun(self):
        print("arun:", self.number)
        

tool_1 = MyTool()
tool_2 = MyTool(number=321)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please find solution below

```
    from langchain import LLMMathChain
    from langchain.agents import AgentType, initialize_agent
    from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
    from langchain.tools import BaseTool
    from typing import  Any

    class MyTool(BaseTool):
        name = "Custom Tool"
        description = "This tool multiplies a number by itself"

        def _run(self, number: str) -> Any:
            return float(number) * float(number)

    # Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
    if __name__ == '__main__':

        llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0)
        llm_math_chain = LLMMathChain(llm=llm, verbose=True)

        tools = [MyTool()]

        agent = initialize_agent(
            tools, 
            llm, 
            agent=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION, 
            verbose=True, max_iterations=3,
            early_stopping_method='generate'
        )

        agent(
            "Result of 5"
        )
```

Comment: Thanks @ZKS for your answer, but the thing is that the property I want to add is quite big (a database) and that's why I wanted to move its initialization to __init__, so that I don't create it each time I run the tool